# How to define a measure, measure space, measurable function

Tags: measure-theory

I've seen a number of sources defining these basic things in different ways, some of which are theorems in my course instead of definitions, so I'm having trouble understanding how to think of them. Could someone quickly define these for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two sets.

Also, let $\mathcal{M}_X$ be a $\sigma$-algebra of $X$ then we say $(X, \mathcal{M}_X)$ is a **measurable space**.

We say a function $f:(X, \mathcal{M}_X)\rightarrow (Y, \mathcal{M}_Y)$ is **$\mathcal{M}_X$-measurable** provide $f^{-1}(A) \in \mathcal{M}_X$ for every $A \in \mathcal{M}_Y$.

A **measure** on $(X, \mathcal{M}_X)$ is a nonnegative extend real-valued function $\mu:\mathcal{M}_x \rightarrow \overline{\mathbb{R}}_{\geq 0}$ with the properties

- $\mu(\emptyset) = 0$
- For any disjoint collection of $\{E_n\} \subset \mathcal{M}_X$, we have that $\mu(\cup E_n) = \sum \mu(E_n)$.

Lastly, we call the triplet $(X, \mathcal{M}_X, \mu)$ a **measure space**.

Comment: Thank you so much. Simply having them together in one paragraph is so helpful.